# Python 3.6.0a3 works for a while then fails on ucrtbase.dll Windows 7

Tags: windows, python-3.x, dll

I don't know if anyone else has had this issue? Python 3.5.2, 3.5.5 and now agian using 3.6.0a3.Sudden unexplained python failure to start. Ide Idle Shows Fatal when trying to start when hours earlier all was fine. Have had this happen now three times. Details Below.

pythonw.exe 
   3.6.150.1013 
   585cd097 
   ucrtbase.DLL 
   10.0.10586.9 
   5642c5f8 
   40000015 
   0008469a 
   9a0 
   01d29a9be7dc282e 
   C:-----my path to it 
   C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.DLL 
   261c485f-068f-11e7-a405-c80aa953b2de

I will re install again and may have to revert back to earlier versions at 3.3. Any help in Preventing this or knowing what causes it would be great Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to use the development version, get 3.6.0.  If python does not start, no python application can run, so IDLE is not relevant.

I strongly suspect your ucrtbase.dll is either corrupt or out-of-date.  On my Win10 system, I have version  10.0.14393.0.  I don't know if it should be the same on Win 7.  Do you have Windows Update turned on?

In any case, other people have had problems with ucrtbase.dll.  See for example, this [tracker issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue28948).  It refers to this [ucrtbase.dll update download page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows).

Comment: Yea that had to be it,, the Version was 10.0.105896 and was last updated in 2015. I did a reinstall--Repair Exe from the install executable from Python after updating the dll file. Its back working now,,I still dont know why it had not upgraded automatically. I had windows upgrade on and it has upgraded many files daily but not this ucrtbase.dll which is a bit odd. Probably because Windows is slowly depricating older versions i assume. They want everyone up to Win 10 i guess i'll have to conform lol, Thanks !

Comment: @rodeone2, I think the Universal CRT updates are just "recommended" in Windows 7, and maybe you don't have your system configured to automatically install recommended updates.